# How to store a property file in the resources folder

Tags: java, maven

I'm creating and updating a property file in a Java Project.
That project is used as a library for other project.

So I get the properties files in the following way:

```
Properties p =new Properties(); 
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        try (InputStream stream = cl.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
            p.load(stream);
        }
```

I need to use `getResourceAsStream` in order to make this works in the library.

So If I try to store in the following way.

```
p.store(new FileOutputStream(fileName), null);
```

The file appears in the root of the project, but not in src/main/resources where it should...

So where can I make this works, considering than in needs to work for the src and for the target folder?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me but `p.store(new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/" + fileName), null);` should do it.

Comment: Yeah, I know... that’s the reason I didn’t do it... I’m asking for a dynamic way of saving the file in the resource folder whenever it is... the same way I’m doing when u los the file. Please note that there I’m not using src/main/resources, the class loader already knows where to look for that file